# Fantasy book: man discovers a fantasy kingdom in his father's cabin, falls in love with a nymph/driad, is attacked by a bad guy who is his brother

Tags: story-identification, books

Man returns to his father's cabin which has been abandoned. He discovers some type of fantasy kingdom, falls in love with this fantasy female girl (like dryad or Nymph or something).

Someone ends up attacking or killing the girl and he has to go in track the bad guy down. The bad guy ends up being his brother who he's supposed to kill or something like that.

Sorry don't know how long ago it was published, I read it in prison like 15+ years ago, it looked like an old book, and didn't have a cover.
Some of the details could be off also but that's the gist of it, I think I remember something about a tree growing in the middle of the cabin/house

Comment: Doesn’t fit the description exactly, but sounds kind of like World of Tiers.

Comment: If this is accepted by the OP as Mythago Wood, then it would be a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186857/a-forest-of-unreal-inhabitants/186860#186860 this question as well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wonder if this is a memory of [Mythago Wood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mythago_Wood) by Robert Holdstock.

This is a long and involved story, but it does involve the protagonist, Stephen Huxley, returning to his father's house on the edge of a wood. His father and brother have disappeared.

It turns out the father and the brother, Christian, have gone into the wood and been trapped there. Time flows differently in the wood so at the time the story starts Christian has been in the woods for many years and has become savage and violent. There is a confrontation one night when Christian returns to the house and attempts to kill Stephen. At the end of the story Stephen goes into the wood to hunt down Christian, and in the penultimate chapter:

> He finds and kill Christian.

The girl would be Guiwenneth, who is a *mythago* i.e. a creature from folklore generated in some unspecified way by the beliefs of people. She gets killed and regenerated several times as I recall, though I forget the details as it's a long time since I read the book and it is a rather involved plot.

There is one point in the story where Stephen finds that a tree has grown up through his father's house.

Comment: Omfg that's it!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you, thank you, thank you!!!!!! Holy crap it's been bugging me for years.